# Setting the value of insert parameter of SqlDataSource in codebehind

Tags: c#, parameters, insert, code-behind, sqldatasource

I have this `SqlDataSource` in my form:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 

        InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [contact] ([Name], [phone], [email], [comment], [time]) VALUES (@Name, @phone, @email, @comment, @time)" 
        oninserting="SqlDataSource1_Inserting" >
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TBname" Name="Name" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TBphone" Name="phone" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TBemail" Name="email" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TBmessage" Name="comment" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
        </InsertParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

And I have this function which has to save the values of TextBoxes in first four fields and current time in fifth field:

```
protected void SaveToDB(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        SqlDataSource1.InsertParameters["time"].DefaultValue = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        SqlDataSource1.Insert();
}
```

4 of 5 fields get their values from some TextBoxes in my form. now problem is the last field: `time` which I can't set it's value. When the function runs, gives you this error:

> Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: String or
>   binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated.

What should I do?

thank you for taking time.

Comment: DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
try this

Comment: @JaneDoe: Yes! that'll do. first, please write your your comment as an answer so i can tick it true answer.
type of "time" field in my db was char(10), which i made it char(Max) and it's good now.
thank you,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
```

"String or binary data would be truncated." usually has to do with fields in databases having a smaller size then what you're trying to put into it.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to use the SQL GetDate function directly in the InsertCommand without using code-behind.

```
InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [contact] ([Name], [phone], [email], [comment], [time]) VALUES (@Name, @phone, @email, @comment, GetDate())"
```